# Gitlab CI - Pipeline for lintr

Tags: r, gitlab-ci

I want to have a pipeline in gitlab which performs static code analysis with lintr.
This is the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: r-base
variables:
  ALLOWED_WARNINGS: 0
  ALLOWED_NOTES: 0
  NO_IMPORTS: 0


check:
  script:
  - Rscript -e "Sys.setenv(GITHUB_PAT = 'my_pat')"
  - Rscript -e "install.packages(c('lintr', 'rcmdcheck', 'usethis', 'remotes'))"
  - Rscript -e "remotes::install_github('jumpingrivers/inteRgrate', auth_token = 'my_pat')"
  - Rscript -e "inteRgrate::check_lintr(path = '.')"
```

//EDIT
However I get this error message:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies ‘lintr’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘usethis’ are not available for package ‘inteRgrate’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/inteRgrate’
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
$ Rscript -e "inteRgrate::check_lintr(path = '.')"
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘inteRgrate’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Since when does `install.packages` look on github? I'm inferring that that's what you are intending with `auth_token`. My guess is that there is a clue included in the output before `no package called 'inteRgrate'`.

Comment: You are right auth_token is only necessary when installing from github. I pasted the entire error message.

Comment: Is that really all of the error messages? The first `ERROR:` line suggests that this is just the portion about installing `inteRgrate`, and there might have been warnings/errors about installation attempts of the other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Should be just a question of "nested" doubled quotes. Are these syntaxes acceptable?

```
 - Rscript -e 'check_lintr(path = ".")'
```

or

```
 - Rscript -e "check_lintr(path = .)"
```

As suggested in the note by r2evans this should be a simpler syntax:

```
 - Rscript -e "check_lintr()"
```

Comment: It actually does not even get to that point. Even just calling the library is not possible.

Comment: I cannot see how `path = .` would work: the `.` is often used in `%>%`-pipes as a place-holder for data from the previous call in the pipeline, but in normal R (as it would be in `Rscript`) it fails with `Error: object '.' not found` (and `check_lintr` does no NSE to infer what is meant). However, the default is [`path = "."`](https://github.com/jumpingrivers/inteRgrate/blob/master/R/check_lintr.R#L47), so omitting `path=` completely would be equivalent, aka `Rscript -e "check_lintr()"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `verbose` flag to install.packages() so you can see what is going on.

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer.